# Angular 4: this._http.request is not a function

Tags: angular, authentication, http-headers

I've implemented auth with my apps and I use a custom [AuthHttp](https://github.com/ItsDizzy/angular2-auth/blob/master/src/auth.http.ts) in my code. But when I run my app, I have this error

> this._http.request is not a function

I don't install the module. I just want to use AuthHttp. So, I've only imported AuthHttp, AuthModule,IAuthConfig and AuthConfig directly in my app
In my appModule, I've imported AuthModule

`imports: [
    ...,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ]`

AuthHttp:

```
constructor(options: AuthConfig, private _http: Http, private _options: RequestOptions) {
    this.config = options.getConfig();
}

private mergeOptions(providedOpts: RequestOptionsArgs, defaultOpts?: RequestOptions) {
    let newOptions = defaultOpts || new RequestOptions();
    if (this.config.globalHeaders) {
        this.setGlobalHeaders(this.config.globalHeaders, providedOpts);
    }

    newOptions = newOptions.merge(new RequestOptions(providedOpts));

    return newOptions;
}

private requestHelper(requestArgs: RequestOptionsArgs, additionalOptions?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let options = new RequestOptions(requestArgs);
    if (additionalOptions) {
        options = options.merge(additionalOptions);
    }

    return this.request(new Request(this.mergeOptions(options, this._options)));
}

public setGlobalHeaders(headers: Array<Object>, request: Request | RequestOptionsArgs) {
    if (!request.headers) {
        request.headers = new Headers();
    }

    headers.forEach((header: Object) => {
        let key: string = Object.keys(header)[0];
        let headerValue: string = (header as any)[key];
        (request.headers as Headers).set(key, headerValue);
    });
}

public request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
        return this.get(url, options); // Recursion: transform url from String to Request
    }

    // from this point url is always an instance of Request;
    let req: Request = url as Request;
    let token: string = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    return this.requestWithToken(req, token);
}

private requestWithToken(req: Request, token: string): Observable<Response> {
    req.headers.set(this.config.headerName, this.config.headerPrefix + token);
    return this._http.request(req);
}
```

and I use authHttp like this

`   @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

```
constructor(
    private _authHttp: AuthHttp,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
}

getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    // get users from api
    return this._authHttp.get('/api/users')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}}
```

And error happens here (in AuthHttp)

```
    private requestWithToken(req: Request, token: string): Observable<Response> {
    req.headers.set(this.config.headerName, this.config.headerPrefix + token);
    return this._http.request(req);
}
```

AuthModule:

```
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(config?: IAuthConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: AuthModule,
        providers: [
            {
                provide: AuthHttp,
                useFactory: provideAuthHttp,
                deps: [
                    Http,
                    RequestOptions
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  }}

export function provideAuthHttp(config: IAuthConfig, http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(config), http, options);}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can we see your code at all?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I use exactly class from the link.

Comment: Have you installed the module? It'd also help if we could see your code.

Comment: No, this module is not fully compatible with angularCli. So I want to create extension. But I have this error

Comment: Are you bringing in the Http module in your constructor?

Comment: yes 

constructor(options: AuthConfig, private _http: Http, private _options: RequestOptions)

Comment: can you add your total service file including your headers and constructor.